# Any web mapping solution for mapping points and manage 1:n relationship?

Tags: web-mapping, carto, arcgis-online, mapbox

I need to show on a web map some points (> 12.000) ... I know that there are many solution for that, also for free (CartoDB, MapBox, ArcGIS On Line, ecc ... ), starting from some shapefiles. That is not my problem

My problem is the follow: I've a table with this structure

TABLE_1: key, x-coord, y-coord, attr-1, attr-2 .....attr-n

and another table with this structure

TABLE_2: key, description

Selecting a value for KEY in TABLE_2 there are several rows in TABLE_1 for that KEY value (1:n relationship).

I'd like to select a value in TABLE_2 and show (or better, point out ...) the points of related rows in TABLE_1 on my map.

I'd like to find a solution without writing "ad hoc" code because my customer is really entry level on GIS or web mapping and I've to keep as more simple as possible my solution.

Any suggestion or example about a situation like this one?

Comment: ArcGIS online solution http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/02/18/related-tables-exploring-new-ways-to-use-collector-for-arcgis/

Comment: Thank for the link, but I should have ArcMap and I don't have it .....

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ArcGIS workflow you could use:

You could take your shapefiles and bring them into a geodatabase and create a relationship class between the features and the tables (1 to M) then publish it to an ArcGIS Server as a feature service or as a hosted feature service to ArcGIS Online. Then you can configure your popup to show feature information and related record information or from the popup you can bring up the related table and show the related records. Then if you need to do any field data collection the Collector app supports related records and you could download that map and create new records or edit existing and it will respect the relationship setup.